# How to access the column# of a GridLayout programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-gridlayout

I am working on a connect 4 game. I'm trying to work out the logic for the app to be able to access the coordinates of each token ImageView so that it can work out if four have been connected. But I've looked high and low over the documentation and I can't seem to find a method in either GridLayout or GridLayout.LayoutParams that would return either the row or column of a child. The GridLayout.spec seems to only have methods to set specs, not return them. Am I missing something?

How would you go about retrieving the column or row number of a child view?

Edit: I don't have the code in front of me because I'm out of my home and my project is only saved locally. However, if it helps, It's a GridLayout over a RelativeLayout with four ImageViews that read vaguely thusly:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="@dimen/tokensize"
android:layout_height="@dimen/tokensize"
android:layout_column="0"
android:layout_row="0"//or "1" or "2" or "3"
android:src="@drawable/token"
android:id="@+id/tokenXbyY"/>
```

I don't have any java to show because that's what I'm trying to figure out. Thank for all the help.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what you have done?

Comment: Unfortunately my full code will have to wait until tonight, I'd just posted and then left the house assuming someone had just a generic answer, and it's only saved locally. That was my mistake. Let me edit my question.